# joomla:how to show a image popup to enter into website

Tags: php, joomla

I want to show a click-able image popup on my home page of my website. 
when user clicks on that image further they can view the website.

Answer (score 0):

Use anchor text around it...

```
<a href="<URL TO WHERE YOU WANT TO GO>" ><img src="<PATH TO IMAGE>" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is probably to use a third party extension like SplashR or similar:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/popups-a-iframes/11693